# Why my app is not connected to the localhost server?

Tags: php, android, authentication

currently I am working on login and register tutorial. I have followed the tutorial completely but it failed. My Php scripts are fine, they are connected to my localhost server. However, when I am running on my app, it does not work and not respond at all, please help me to check and see if there is any error. My manifest.xml has already written the code permission internet. My app just couldn't link up and show no respond.

this is my linking class, BackgroundTask.class

```
package com.example.lam.loginregistertest2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpConnection;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by LAM on 3/8/2015.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context ctx;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://192.168.43.225/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp.login.php";

    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register"))
    {
String name = params[1];
        String age = params[2];
        String username = params[3];
        String password = params[4];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

        return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

register.php

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$name = isset ($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
$age = isset ($_POST["age"]) ? $_POST["age"] : "";
$username = isset ($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
$password = isset ($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : "";

$sql_query = "insert into user values('$name','$age','$username','$password');";

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)){
//echo "<h3>Data Insertion Success...</h3>";
}else{
//echo "Data insertion error..".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

init.php

```
<?php
$db_name = "test";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "cheehong";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if(!$con){
//echo "Connection Error...".mysql_connect_error();

}else{
//echo "<h3>Database Connection Successful...</h3>";
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$username = "ivan";
$password = "12";

$sql_query = "select name from user where username like '$username' and   password like '$password';";
$result = mysqli_query ($con,$sql_query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row["name"];
echo "<h3>Hello welcome".$name."</h3>";
}else{
echo "No info is available.";
}
?>
```

Register.class

```
package com.example.lam.loginregistertest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends Activity {
EditText ET_NAME, ET_USER_NAME,ET_USER_PASS,ET_AGE;
String name,age, username,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    ET_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    ET_AGE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
    ET_USER_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);
    ET_USER_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_pass);

  }

public void userReg(View view)
{
name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
age = ET_AGE.getText().toString();
username = ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
password = ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
String method = "register";
BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
backgroundTask.execute(method,name,age,username,password);
finish();
}
}
```

Comment: String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php"; may be this url?

Comment: Note: ``"select name from user where username like '$username' and   password like '$password';";`` use ``=`` instead of ``like`` if you use like it does not need to be exactly the password/user it can be just one character

Comment: `login and register tutorial.`. Which one?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3O3CY75ITY

This is the tutorial I follow.

Please do recommend me if there is any other good tutorial because I have tried two tutorials. I wonder if it is the problem with my android studio.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_Rk9TiV46o
and this one too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the urls that you are using

```
String reg_url = "http://192.168.43.225/webapp/register.php";
String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp.login.php";
```

both are different

Comment: `both are different`. No. They are different. The next question would be device/emulator?

Comment: I have changed that.But it still the same.

Comment: what is the problem with device/emulator? I have tried it on real device it also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if your server and  device is within the same network? If not make it sure the server is reachable by device.

Comment: What does it mean? How to check if they are in the same network?

Comment: If the browser in android device can hit local url (i.e http://192.168.43.225/webapp/register.php ) then server is reachable by device .

Comment: U mean the URL(i.e 192.168.43.225/webapp/register.php ) can be running on my laptop browser then the server is reachable by my device?

If yes, the browser can run but the device is not running

Comment: Try to load localhost page from browser of android device not laptop. If browser of android device is not able to connect to the server, then your application will not be able to hit url.

Comment: My browser on device cannot log on to the link. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Make sure your android  device and laptop is connected in the same router.

Comment: Do you mean to connect them under same Wifi connection ?